# What are the best practices pertaining to signing your git commits on GitHub?

Tags: gnupg, git, github

On GitHub, anyone can push a commit with your name and email. To combat this, you can [gpg sign your commits](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification/signing-commits).

However, in the scenario that the private key is exposed, the only option GitHub offers is to remove the associated public key. Unfortunately, this also marks all your past commits as `unverified`.

At this point, my initial thoughts were to securely shred the existing gpg private key and start using a new gpg key every x months so that only the very latest commits would be marked unverified. With this approach, I don't see any problems as long as GitHub does not have a limit on the keys that can be uploaded. However, I was wondering: What is considered to be the best practice pertaining to this situation?